# Why does 012 % 10 = 0 in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying following program.

```
int var = 012;
int result = var % 10;
```

output:

```
result = 0
```

I am not able to understand why java is not able to consider 012 as 12.

Comment: Because 012 is an octal number. See duplicate link.

Answer (score 12):

In Java, integer literals that start with `0` are interpreted as [**octal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) numbers.

So, `012` is the number 1 x 8 + 2 = 10 (in decimal), not 12 (decimal).

`012 % 10 == 10 % 10 == 0`